# SSRS Visual Studio Beginner Help Needed

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

***EDIT*** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toGYY.jpg) - this link is the image for the data set I am working with - the data set is an example

- I'm quite new to SSRS and the person who is teaching it to me is also struggling with what I'm trying to show, however I feel it must be simple and we are making it too complicated when trying to resolve the issue!

Within my SQL data that will be shown in the SSRS report, it shows what a user has rated themselves on a technical level for a product my company produces.

Within my SQL report, rather than counting or summing this number I simply want it to show the rating that the user has given.  However, if I were to do on a summary page in excel for example, I would simply type '='A1' for example.

However SSRS doesn't seem to have this, and I don't have a glossary to hand, and when I've googled it, I think it's such a simple answer, i Can't find it anywhere!

Apologies for the absolute lack of knowledge with this, but I look forward to any help and kind hearted jokes at my expense!

Products    Ordering    Technical   Name
Product 1   10  8   Talha Khan
Product 2   10  10  Talha Khan
Product 3   10  8   Talha Khan
Product 4   10  8   Talha Khan
Product 5   0   0   Talha Khan
Product 6   10  8   Talha Khan
Product 7   10  10  Talha Khan
Product 8   0   0   Talha Khan
Product 1   7   10  Jay Potter
Product 2   7   10  Jay Potter
Product 3   0   7   Jay Potter
Product 4   0   0   Jay Potter
Product 5   0   0   Jay Potter
Product 6   8   6   Jay Potter
Product 7   8   7   Jay Potter
Product 8   10  10  Jay Potter

Comment: can you give us a sample of the dataset that you are pulling from? also can you confirm that you are actually using mysql (like your tag) or did you mean to tag this as 'mssql' (Microsoft SQL)?

Comment: Apologies, I am using 'Microsoft SAL Server Management Studio 2010, and VB 2010. I'll amend the tag.                  Also, in terms of a data set, I'll try and copy and paste in as a picture to this and the original post however as I'm a newbie I think it takes some time for the picture to come through

Comment: Great, a picture always helps.  Just screenshot and save the file locally, then upload that file when you are editing your post.

Comment: Cheers Daniel, for some reason it saying there's a problem with Imgur! I'll try again tomorrow, however it's basically a list, with user name in one column, Order rating in the next, Technical rating in the next, then the Company name for who they work for. The more I look at it, I think I want to show, if for example Dave Smith, Works for 'Company 1, and his Order Rating is 7, the coloumn to show 7, not to add or sum, just simply show the value of 7.  thanks for your patience with this

Comment: Is there just one row per user?  It sounds like you just need to insert a "tablix" into the report and pull the data out of your dataset (all point and click)

Comment: Placing a picture even made up in Excel displaying that what you are getting and what you actually want to achieve will make life easy for all.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the bigger questions about what you are trying to show and whether this is the correct way...

You can reference a different textbox or report item on the page in an expression like this:

```
=ReportItems!TextBox1.Value
```

You can also do a [lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function) on a dataset to find a particular value like this

```
=Lookup("MyLookupValue", "DatasetLookupValue", "ReturningColumn", "DatasetName")
```

and you can also reference a single row dataset like this:

```
=First(Fields!Name.Value, "DatasetName")
```